# Sorting object on insertion in HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

As per my knowledge of collection framework, if we need to sort an object on insertion, we can use `TreeMap` and that object class should override `compareTo()` method of comparable class.

But, I want to know, **is** there any way through which we can achieve the same result in **`HashMap`**? Is there any utility which will enable it to be sorted, while inserting objects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, `HashMap` is not a sorted map by design, it even does not implement `SortedMap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `HashMap` is not a sorted map by design, it even does not implement `SortedMap` interface. See [`HashMap` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

**EDIT (from the comment below)**

Since `TreeMap` it's sorted, you have to either use `Comparable` keys or provide a `Comparator` implementation to a constructor, see [TreeMap javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to know , Is there any alternative way to achieve that or any utility library

Comment: The most famous alternative is `TreeMap`. Since it's sorted, you have to either use `Comparable` keys or provide a `Comparator` implementation to a constructor, see [`TreeMap` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do not drop TreeMap too fast! `TreeMap` allowes to use a `Comparator` instead of the `compareTo()` method.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Person {
    private int age;

    public static class AgeComperator implements Comparator {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object top, Object bottom) {

            return ((Person) top).age - ((Person) bottom).age;
        }
    }

    public Person(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<Person, String> map = new TreeMap(new AgeComperator());
        map.put(new Person(18), "True");
        map.put(new Person(29), "False");
        System.out.println(map.keySet().iterator().next().age);
    }

}
```

As you can see, Person has no `compareTo`-method.

Comment: Please, read the question carefully. The question was asked about `HashMap`: "IS there any way through which we can achieve same in **HashMap**?" So your post (about `TreeMap`) doesn't provide an answer to the original question.

Comment: Ok, got it. BTW, I mentioned the same note on comparator in the comment to my answer, but somebody downvoted it. The world is unfair :( You answer has a typo in `Comperator` word, it should be `Comparator` :) Catch an upvote! :)

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev Yes, the rejecter was `Comunity (admin)` i saw the edit of you and totaly agree your edit and declide the reject from the user Comunity! Oh, I guess it was a concurrent update, and comunity did not take the work to merge theese edits.

Answer (score -1):

No, `HashMap` is an unsorted data structure.

Comment: Is there any alternative or utility library to achieve that?

Comment: You can use a `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` (javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html )